# Comprehensive cross browser listing of Javascript function support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm getting back into the wild world of cross browser compatibility, and have come across a few nagging issues with Javascript compatibility between browsers.

For example, I use style inheritance a great deal in my CSS sheets, so if I need to edit an element's style, I have to use `window.getComputedStyle(**element**, [pseudoElement]).getPropertyValue(**style**)`

Using that one line of code requires me to know that Firefox v<4 requires a pseudoElement object, whereas other browsers consider it an optional parameter.  In addition, Firefox and Opera require that **style** fit the CSS property name, such as `font-size`, where IE needs the name in Javscript syntax `fontSize` due to interpreting the hypen in the CSS syntax as a minus sign.

This one example took a few hours of figuring out why earlier versions of IE were implementing my text-resize script with the script's default size, rather than the element's computed size.   Mozilla's site is a great reference, but is limited to their browsers.  Is there a good comprehensive cross browser function listing?

Comment: is there any reason you're not using jquery?

Comment: That's why cross-browser libraries like jQuery exist in the first place.

Comment: jQuery supports a handful of recent browsers, it is not particularly cross-browser. It is more multi-browser. It works mostly because modern browsers are converging on standards.

Comment: I'm a JS beginner and basically hunting around for the functions needed to get my page running.  I'd like to get more comfortable with JS before jumping into jQuery

Comment: @RobG jQuery supports **all** relevant desktop browsers, which makes it fully cross-browser. What does "multi-browser" mean?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "relevant". If that includes anything other than `IE 6.0+, FF 2.0+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+, Chrome` you're out of luck.  The web is an open platform, any browser in use is "relevant" for some, for others jQuery's limited set is sufficient. Multi-browser means it's built to run in only those browsers it claims to support, "fully cross browser" would mean in runs in *any* browser, not just some. Of course the jQuery people may define "fully cross browser" as only the browsers they support.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas But not mobile browsers, for which you need jQuery mobile.  honestly, if the same framework doesn't support both I'll just write code myself that does that.

Comment: @Michael Could you give examples of jQuery features that fail in mobile browsers? It was my assumption that the entire jQuery API works in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you will find a single site that lists them all—there are just way too many incompatibilities and far too many browsers to consider. Some help can be found on the [Quirksmode compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) and there is also the Thomas Lahn's [ECMAScript support matrix](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/).

Other than that, you can troll through various javscript library source code and look for comments, however use with caution as often the comments are ill informed or poorly worded - they aren't really meant to be a resource for browser incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) does have a notice at the bottom of each page about browser support for the object/function. But yeah, it's not really an exhaustive source.

So for browser compatibility, PPK's [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) is the most comprehensive source, I think.